# How to access Linux server from an ip?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, port, forward

I would like to know how to make my Linux Server accesible for anyone around the world. I currectly can access it via 192.168.1.22 locally on my network. I would like it to be accesible through and IP or a domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting all ports to be accessible then you can make the box a DMZ on your router and set a static IP, then you are done. If you want it to be accessible through SSH which is what I am going to assume, then you need to set a static IP for the box forward the internal IP address and port in your router and then optionally set up DDNS settings if available. At that point you will be able to access the box from any public network. If you need help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Either get a static IP address from your Internet Service Provider, or use Dynamic DNS to map a domain name to a dynamic IP address.

One well known Dynamic DNS provider is NoIP

http://www.noip.com/free/

In any case, you probably have a NAT "firewall" that blocks all incoming traffic, so you'll need to configure the firewall to allow ports through that you want to server. Typical Linksys / Netgear NAT firewalls / Wifi routers allow you to port forward to a single private IP address.

Finally, you should make sure your ISP allows running a server. Though most of them dont mind, because the upload speed is throttled by design, you still want to check the terms of service.